# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at new Schema.extend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, meanjs, mongoose-schema

After installing a new package mongoose-schema-extend 0.2.0 I get the following error when I run the gulp command:

> C:\Users\Artan\Desktop\new-ct\node_modules\mongoose-schema-extend\index.js:17
>   newSchema.callQueue.forEach(function(k) {
>                        ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>       at new Schema.extend (C:\Users\Artan\Desktop\new-ct\node_modules\mongoose-schema-extend\index.js:17:22)

My module looks like below after installing the mongoose-schema-extend:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    BaseSchema = require('../../../../config/models/base_schema');

    /**
     * Partner Schema
     */
    var PartnerSchema = new BaseSchema.extend({
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill Partner name',
            trim: true
        },
        descr: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill Partner Description',
            trim: true
        },
        user: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    });

    var Partner = mongoose.model('Partner', PartnerSchema);

    module.exports = Partner;
```

Answer (score 0):

changed var `PartnerSchema = new BaseSchema.extend({` to var `PartnerSchema =BaseSchema.extend({` and it worked.